# 64-bit application runs on 32-bit x86 android?

Tags: android, linux, x86, operating-system, x86-64

I have a computer that runs a 64bit linux, as can be seen by **uname -a**:

```
Linux meitarb-IdeaPad-U430p 3.13.0-43-generic #72-Ubuntu SMP Mon Dec 8 19:35:06 UTC 2014 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

And a rooted android device that runs a 32bit linux, as can be seen by **uname -a**:

```
Linux localhost 3.4.34-850131 #1 SMP PREEMPT Tue Nov 26 14:21:45 KST 2013 i686 unknown
```

I've used **adb push** command in order to copy the **dd** binary from the 64bit linux to the android device:

```
$ adb push `which dd` /data/my_bin/
```

The **dd** binary is compiled for 64bit as can be see with the **file** command:

```
$ file `which dd`
/bin/dd: ELF 64-bit LSB  executable, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked (uses shared libs), for GNU/Linux 2.6.24, BuildID[sha1]=bd9a50b8e781047585f94fde7eb1f9703dfbde28, stripped
```

I've used the **dd** binary on my android and it works just fine.. Its all nice and all... But why does it work?! As far as i know 64bit compiled binary isn't supposed to work on 32bit kernel, but it does.

**#EDIT**

Unfortunately in the end it seems like it was just a stupid action of me.. On the device, I added the folder i've copied the **dd** binary to to the PATH enviroment variable. But the catch was that there was another **dd** binary compiled correct for 32-bit in the PATH directories.. Then when i ran it, i actually ran the correct **dd** binary.

Comment: I do not understand why `/data/my_bin` path is used in adb command line, but then `file` checks `/bin/dd`.

Comment: The path i gave to the adb command is the path where the file will be located on the android device after the copy action. I ran the file command on my computer, but it really doesn't matter weather i would have ran it there or in the device, the result will be the same.